# Identify stylus barrel button (win32)

Tags: c++, winapi, stylus-pen

I am creating an application that uses the tablet API for windows and so far I was able to capture the input of the stylus succesfully. I am able to handle the movement, stylus down and up events and pressure. What I am still missing is the ability to identify the barrel button pressed. While I am capturing the `StylusButtonDown` event, this is fired also when the stylus is down on the tablet.

For reference here is my (ideal) implementation:

```cpp
STDMETHOD(StylusButtonDown)(IRealTimeStylus* rts, STYLUS_ID id, const GUID* guid, POINT* pt)
{
  if (BARREL_BUTTON_ID == *guid) {
    s_buttonDown = true;

    // DEBUG
    std::cout << "[StylusButtonDown]" << std::endl;
    // DEBUG
  }
  return S_OK;
}
```

The problem I have is to fill in the `BARREL_BUTTON_ID` constant. Any expert with an idea?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not print out the GUIDs you get from different events, and put the relevant one into your program? They don't seem to actually be documented anywhere... BTW, what exact value do you get for your barrel button? Searching the web for its explicit value might yield some docs.

Comment: This is what I am doing atm but it seemed kinda hacky. Maybe somebody knows the correct way of doing this.

Comment: If you post the value of the GUID here, someone might be skillful enough to find the relevant info on the web.

Comment: If you can limit your application to Windows 10 and later, you could evaluate using the Windows Runtime instead. It encapsulates all those quirks that have accumulated over decades, and provides a clean interface. See [Pen interactions and Windows Ink in Windows apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/pen-and-stylus-interactions).